# Get top 'n' records by report_id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a simple view in my MSSQL database. It consists of the following fields:

```
report_id INT
ym VARCHAR -- YYYY-MM
keyword VARCHAR(MAX)
visits INT
```

I can easily get the top 10 keyword hits with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM top_keywords
WHERE ym BETWEEN '2010-05' AND '2010-05'
ORDER BY visits DESC
```

Now where it gets tricky is where I have to get the top 10 records for each `report_id` in the given date range (`ym BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date`).

How would I go about getting the top 10 for each report_id? I've stumbled across suggestions involving the use of ROW_NUMBER() and RANK(), but have been vastly unsuccessful in their implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY report_id ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
         FROM top_keywords
         WHERE ym BETWEEN '2010-05' AND '2010-05') TK
WHERE RN <= 10
```

Comment: +1 Much simpler than mine. I don't know why I got hung up on doing a completely unnecessary JOIN! You've left a `SELECT 0` in rather than `visits desc` though.

Comment: While the others were somewhat helpful, this was almost spot-on for what I needed. I changed the `ORDER BY` to use the `visits` field, and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested (since I don't have a mssql install at home), but this should be close...

```
with IDs (ID) as (
  select
    report_id
  from
    top_keywords tk
  where
    tk.ym between @start_date and @end_date
    and row_number() over(partition by report_id order by visits desc) <= 10
)
  select
    top.*
  from
    top_keywords top
    join IDs on IDs.ID = top.report_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do a single query or a series of queries?  For a series of queries, you can

- Step 1) Find all unique report IDs
- Step 2) Use query above for the top
  10 for that report

Or do you really want a giant query that will give you all the results? How many results do you want, 10 per report id?

Comment: A giant query isn't necessarily a bad thing, but that is what I want: The top 10 per report id.